# Photos host with embed button for website

Tags: images, cloud-storage

I have a wedding website where I'd like people to be able to upload pictures they took at the wedding, but the website is static. Is there a free (or cheap) photos host that can give me an embeddable button to upload directly to my album on their service?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a platform like Google Drive. Google Drive also allows to embed folders into your website. Here is a Blog Post how you can do it: https://mori.pages.dev/blog/embed-google-drive-folders

Since you have a lot of free space within Google Drive this may be a gratis solution.

**Disclosure: I work for PollUnit**

Another idea would be using a PollUnit [photo contest](https://pollunit.com/en/photo-contest).

This also has a free plan but you should take a look at the file limits. The free plan only allows up to 20 images. You can only activate submissions and deactivate voting which would result in a image uploading platform. But maybe a heart rating is also a nice to have for your use case. You can embed the contest in your website with a nice looking gallery and lightbox. You also can make your own design. You can also book PollUnit just for a single month.

Answer (score 0):

They can upload them in [Imgur](https://imgur.com/) and send you link to their album.